# Extracting parts of a line in a text file into a new file in C programming

Tags: c, unix, text, line

I am trying to extract parts of a line from a text file, and output it into a new file in C programming under the UNIX platform.  For example, I have file1.txt as follow:

Device: ABCDE1

Date: 12/12/12

Operator=John Doe

and i would like it to display in file2.txt as:

ABCDE1, 12/12/12, John Doe.

Here is the code I have so far, I got the opening and writing to file part down, but just could not figure out how to extract the info after "Device:", with out displaying "Divice:" it self.  My code just copies the first line of file1, and puts it in file 2:

---

```
#include "stdio.h"
main()
{
    FILE *fs, *ft;
    char ch ;
char file[100]="" ;
char Device [100];
char Date [80];

printf ("Enter file name and directory:");
scanf ("%s",&file);

    fs = fopen (file, "r") ;
    if ( fs == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open source file" ) ;
           exit( ) ;
    }

    ft = fopen ( "file2.txt", "w" ) ;
    if ( ft == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
           fclose ( fs ) ;
           exit( ) ;
    }


fscanf(fs, "%s %s", Device,Date);
fprintf(ft, "%s %s\n", Device,Date);


    fclose ( fs ) ;
    fclose ( ft ) ;
return 0;
}
```

---

Is fscanf() a good command to use for this? or Are there any other suggested commands to make this work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

[`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is one possible function to use. You'll get a bit of problem with "John Doe", as the scanf() family of functions treat %s as "whitespace separated strings" - so you will read "John", and then the next step will get Doe and whatever is on the next line, which is probably not what you want.

There are ways around this in fscanf() itself. Alternatively, you can use fgets() to read a whole line, and then split it up with some string functions. Interestingly, the lines have slightly different format, which makes life more challenging.

I'm intentionally not telling you exactly how to do this, because I'm pretty certain a bit part of why you are doing this is to learn. And you learn nothing from copying someone else's work.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yes I am fairly new to programming in C and I am trying to learn.
I did come acrss the fgets() command, and have been reading up online and playing around with it for the past couple of hours or so.  I can't seem to find the right way to make the pointer search for "Device:", "Date:," and extract the characters displayed in the rest of the line. Would you have any recommendations on this part? Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Mats that using fgets and then parsing the line of text is easier than using fscanf.  Look up and learn to use the [strtok function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok).

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad exercise to write a small function `char *find_in_string(char *haystack, char *needle)`
It would take the input string as "haystack", and then work it's way through it to find the ": " or some such, and return the pointer to the remainder of the string. Whilst strtok and other str functions are great for doing this sort of thing, it comes in handy to learn how to do string searching by hand too.

If you post some attempt to do this, I'm sure we can give hints (probably best as a new question)

Comment: Ok so i have this to work, it displays the first line of the file:
 fgets(device, 100, fs);
 fputs(device, ft);
But how can I combine that with     char *find_in_string(char *device:, char *Date)?  I tried a few things with this but have no clue how it works, cannot even get it to compile..

Answer (score 1):

The `fscanf` function reads data from the file (first argument), parses it according to the given format (second argument), and loads up the variables specified (the rest of the arguments) based on the format. See the definition [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/). This means that after your fscanf call, your `Device` and `Date` buffers have the strings `Device:` and `ABCDE1` stored in them. Instead of fprintf'ing both Device and Date, just print Date. You'll now have to set up a loop to go through the whole file, fscanf'ing until you get an EOF flag and printing only the second string on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got my code to work, it uses igets to scan the line of string, and use **printf(&buffer[7]);** to output only the answer after "device:".  And since the record I will be using will have a fixed position for "device, date, operator, etc," I won't even have to search for those words, I just have to simply put my pointer to those lines.

But here is my new question, my current code only reads the first line of the file, how can I make it to read different lines?  For example, if I only want it to read line 1, 2, and 5.

Here is my complete code:

```
  main()
  {
    FILE *fs, *ft ;
    char ch ;
char file[100]="" ;
char line1[50];

printf ("Enter file name and directory:");
scanf ("%s",&file);

    fs = fopen (file, "r") ;
    if ( fs == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open source file" ) ;
    }

    ft = fopen ( "book5.txt", "w" ) ;
    if ( ft == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
           fclose ( fs ) ;
    }

    fgets(line1,50,fs);
printf(&line1[7]);
printf(",");
printf(&line1[7]);

    fclose ( fs ) ;
    fclose ( ft ) ;
 }
```

Thanks for the help!